# Set with empty interior

Tags: general-topology, terminology

What is the name of a set with empty interior? Wikipedia in a older version, say that is a hollow set, but i think that it is false. 
It is true?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Co-dense, perhaps?

Comment: yes it is true thanks!

Comment: On behalf of jargon-weary people, I humbly request such sets to be called "sets with empty interior".

Comment: Very well. I shall.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hereby dub such sets: "co-dense."

Comment: This terminology appears in Engelking's _General Topology_.

Comment: @Arthur: Excellent! I'd have been shocked if I were the first to think of it.

Comment: @CameronBuie thaks!

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_%28topology%29) says that "sets with empty interior have been called boundary sets."